# How to make CountDownTimer count to 1?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

How do I make CountDownTimer count to **1**, not **0**? How do I do that? ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

```
    private void start() {

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            time.setText("Click!");
        }
    };

    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, what do you want to achieve with that counter counting only down to 1?

Comment: After 3,2,1 I want to display "Click", not 0

Comment: `time.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + 1)`?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Man, +1) Otherwise, it won't compile.

Comment: `time.setText("" + Math.ceil(millisUntilFinished / 1000.0))`

Comment: @Lino it actually works! But it displays in decimal number: 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, Click!. How do I make it display without the decamal dot(.)?

Comment: @MichaelRomanchuk what about: `time.setText(String.valueOf((int) Math.ceil(millisUntilFinished / 1000.0)));`

Comment: Thank you both Leny and Gokul Nath KP! Both of these ways work perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of starting from 4000 ms, start from 3000 ms, and add +1 before setting to `TextView`:

```
private void start() {

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setText(String.valueOf((int) Math.ceil(millisUntilFinished / 1000.0)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            time.setText("Click!");
        }
    };

    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: waiting 4 seconds is different than waiting 3 seconds